# Find the values of $a$ and $b$ when the binomial expansion of $\frac{1}{(1+ax)^b}+\frac{1}{(1+bx)^a} = 2-6x+15x^2$

Tags: binomial-theorem

Find the values of $a$ and $b$ when the binomial expansion of $$\frac{1}{(1+ax)^b}+\frac{1}{(1+bx)^a} = 2-6x+15x^2$$ 
So I set up the two equations:
$$(-b)(ax)+(-a)(bx)=-6x$$ and $$\frac{(-b)(-b-1)(ax)^2}{2}+\frac{(-a)(-a-1)(bx)^2}{2}=15x^2$$

I then substituted the first one into the second one to try and solve for $a$, but this hasn't given me the right answer Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which answer did you obtain?

Comment: i obtained a surd for the value of $a$ when its supposed to be 1,3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done almost everything already:
We have that
$$(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)x^2+O(x^3)$$
So
$$\frac{1}{(1+ax)^b}+\frac{1}{(1+bx)^a}=$$
$$(1+ax)^{-b}+(1+bx)^{-a}=$$
$$\left(1-bax+\frac{1}{2}b(b+1)a^2x^2+O(x^3)\right)+\left(1-abx+\frac{1}{2}a(a+1)b^2x^2+O(x^3)\right)=$$
$$2-2abx+\frac{1}{2}(a^2b^2+ba^2+a^2b^2+ab^2)x^2+O(x^3)$$
So we need to have that
$$-2ab=-6$$
$$ab=3$$
And
$$\frac{1}{2}(a^2b^2+ba^2+a^2b^2+ab^2)=15$$
$$2(ab)^2+ab(a+b)=30$$
$$2(3)^2+3(a+b)=30$$
$$a+b=4$$
And I think you can solve the system of equations now.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Compute $ab$ and $a+b$, and use the following result from high school:

> Let $x, y$ two (real or complex) numbers with given sum $s$ and product $p$. Then $x$ and $y$ are the roots of the quadratic equation:
>   $$t^2-st+p=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Find the derivative at $x=0$:
$$\frac{1}{(1+ax)^b}+\frac{1}{(1+bx)^a} = 2-6x+15x^2 \Rightarrow \\
-\frac{ab}{(1+ax)^{b+1}}-\frac{ab}{(1+bx)^{a+1}}=-6+30x \Rightarrow ab=3.$$
Find the 2nd order derivative at $x=0$:
$$\frac{a^2b(b+1)}{(1+ax)^{b+2}}+\frac{ab^2(a+1)}{(1+bx)^{a+2}}=30 \Rightarrow a+b=4.$$
Now you can solve the equations: $ab=3$ and $a+b=4$.